# Kotlin Code to Validate a Confirmation of Password

Tags: kotlin, validation

Need code to validate the confirmation of password, included is the validation of password field:

```
    private fun passwordValidate(text: String?): Boolean {
        var p = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@\$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@\$!%*?&]{5,20}\$")
        var m = p.matcher(text)
        return m.matches()
    }
```

The confirm password I would guess would start of similar as follows:

```
    private fun confirmpasswordValidate(text: String?): Boolean {
        var p = Pattern.compile
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you do not need any extra method to validate the `confirmpassword`. You should first check if the passwords are the same and if they are, then simply check the first password with your `passwordValidate` method.